# reading object from const unordered_map

Tags: c++

Why am I not allowed to read an object from a constant unordered_map?

```
const unordered_map<int, int> z;
int val = z[5]; // compile error
```

The error under clang is the following:

```
error: no viable overloaded operator[] for type 'const
      unordered_map<int, int>'
                        int val = z[5];
```

Considering that the equivalent code using a `const vector` works fine I'm somewhat confused why we get this behavior.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The expression `z[5]` calls a non-const member function of the map.

This is because a map's `operator[]` will insert a new element if the key isn't found, so obviously it has to be non-const.

For a `vector` nothing is inserted by `operator[]`, the element must exist already (or you get undefined behaviour, so the equivalent code would access the 6th element of an empty vector, which is not fine!).

To lookup a key without adding it use:

```
int val = 0;
auto it = z.find(5);
if (it != z.end())
  val = it->second;
```

Comment: In order to be a bit less verbose, you can also use `int val = z.at(5);` -- In which case, you will get an `std::out_of_range` exception if the key is not in the map. Of course, it's not less verbose if you surround it in a try-catch block.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot this behavior of map - I find it quite surprising that looking up a key may insert the default value into the map, but that explains while it's not a const member function. Will accept it in 2 minutes :) (and yes @Benjamin `at` is the best choice for me in the code anyhow, because not finding the value at this point would be a serious error).

Comment: @Voo: It may be surprising at the very first glance, but it immediately becomes clear that nothing else really makes sense.

Comment: @Kerrek Considering that lots of other hashmap implementations don't have this behavior and still work perfectly fine, I may have to disagree with you on that. Imo it's not good design to have a read operation modify state, but that may just be me.

Comment: @Voo: Typical use is like `m["jim"] = 18;`, and you expect that to work whether or not the key already exists, non?

Comment: @Voo, it's not a read operation, it's a read-write operation, so it makes perfect sense when used as KerrekSB shows

Answer (score 24):

As Jonathan already said, the `operator[]` method is non-const because it might add a default value when the item being looked up is not found.

On the other hand, as highlighted from Benjamin in a comment, the `at()` method is available for const as well.

```
const unordered_map<int, int> z;
int val = z.at(5); // Success!
```

The downside is that when the value being looked up is not in the map, a `std::out_of_range` exception is raised, so it has to be managed.

Comment: This actually solved the problem when you need a const unordered_map just as query table, thanks a lot ! Helped!