# Difference between std::unordered_map::operator[] and std::unordered_map::at

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, c++14

I thought the only difference between `std::unordered_map::operator[]` and `std::unordered_map::at` is that `std::unordered_map::at` throws `std::out_of_range` if the key doesn't exist.

However, in the following code snippet, `std::unordered_map::at` works but `std::unordered_map::operator[]` gives a compiler error

```
const unordered_map<char, string> digit2Letters {
    {'2', "abc"},
    {'3', "def"},
    {'4', "ghi"},
};

digit2Letters.at('1') // works good
digit2Letters['1']; // compiler error: no operator "[]" matches these operands
```

Does anyone know why `std::unordered_map::at` works but `std::unordered_map::operator[]` fails?

Comment: `operator[]` is a non-const member function.  Your `map` is `const`.  I'm sure there's a dupe for this.

Comment: `operator[]` doesn't work on const objects.

Comment: Ohh yea. I found a dup here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13354394/reading-object-from-const-unordered-map.

operator[] is non-const as it adds a default value when the key doesn't exist. Makes sense. Thanks!